# using brownie to deploy scripts fails

Tags: brownie

I have been trying to run a python "Hello" code using brownie run scripts/deploy.py
I am obtaining the following output:

```
Brownie v1.19.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 36, in main
    args = docopt(__doc__, more_magic=True)
  File "brownie/utils/docopt.py", line 814, in docopt
    assert instr.opname.startswith("CALL_")
AssertionError:
```

search and charGPT could not help me, can you please?

i treid "brownie run scripts/deploy.py" which contains:

```
def main():
    print("hello!")
```